# How to repo init a manifest file ignoring annotation tag?

Tags: android, git, repo

repo manifest file has a line as below:

```
<project name="something" path="something" revision="some sha"><annotation version="1.2.3" />
```

When I do `repo init` on the manifest, it fails saying:
`fatal: no name in <annotation> within /path/of/manifest.xml`

It works if I change annotation tag in manifest as `<annotation name="version" value="1.2.3" />`, but is there a way to workaround this? I don't want to change those old manifest files, is there a way to do repo init by ignoring "*annotation*" tag?

Answer (score 0):

According to the manifest [format](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.txt), `name` and `value` are required. `repo init` does not have any option that works on it.

Specify another manifest or omit `-m <manifest.xml>` in `repo init`, and leave `-m manifest` to `repo sync`.

You could modify the manifest between `repo init` and `repo sync`, like commenting out the annotation lines or making a new copy without annotation lines. So you don't have to commit the changes.